# What is the quickest way to Recover an NTFS partition?

Tags: windows, diskpart

I've ran the following on the wrong drive in the **diskpart** command in windows:

```
select disk 1
clean
create part pri
```

What is the quickest way I can recover the old partition in the drive?

It was an NTFS partition taking up the whole drive. I think it was a standard partition, not a gpt one, although I'm not entirely sure.

**Update:**

Since there was just one NTFS partition taking up the whole space on the drive, is there a way to just recreate that partition in the partition table, and not have to reformat it?

Comment: I'm not sure how recoverable it will be at this point but you could try using some tool like TestDisk to recover the data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I recover lost/inacessible data from my storage device?](http://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inacessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Comment: @MC10: I've ran TestDisk. The Quick Search took nearly 4 hours, and only found the FAT32 I presume the {{create part pri}} created. I've got the Deeper Search running now.

Comment: @DragonLord, the question you linked to just discusses general data recovery, but nothing on this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I managed to fix it myself. In TestDisk, I had to go to Advanced Options, change the partition type from FAT32 to NTFS (I guess the **diskpart** steps I ran changed the type to FAT32), and then I had to rebuild the boot sector.

Then I went into the Disk Management program included with Windows, and map a drive onto the partition, and I was ready to go! phew!

Comment: You will now learn to quintuple check any partition commands :)

Comment: @Nelson, :D You're not wrong there mate!